# How to prevent others from removing my admob Ads?

Tags: android, admob

I've published an application to Google appmarket.

And I am using admob to gain some profit. Now I find that someone downloaded my app and removed the ads, and published it to some other market, which is not what i want at all.

Here is some code I put in my layout.xml

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/admob_view"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundColor="#000000"
    app:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
    app:keywords=""/>
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

To make it harder you could add the view in Java instead of XML and obfuscate your code.

Comment: how to obfuscate http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Answer (score 3):

It is too late now, but for future versions and apps you can set the Copy Protection to "On" in the Android Market upload page.  It's near the bottom.  I doubt it is fool-proof but it can help keep some of the people likely to do this from being able to.

Comment: Thanks, but i really don't care whether my app is being copied everywhere or not since it's free. but i do care someone hack my app and remove my ads

Comment: If they can't copy it off of their phone, they can't remove the adds and post it elsewhere.

Comment: I'll try this on my next app. Yeah, I take your point, I dont need a bullet-proof solution

Comment: root access (easily enough hacked on most phones) will override this.

Comment: That said, you should combine this solution with Ed Burnette's solution.  These combined should make it nearly bulletproof.

Comment: Do not use Market copy protection. It is deprecated, and mostly pointless.